# UIPickerView not showing calculated values correctly

Tags: ios, swift, struct, uipickerview

I'm making a picker view to display a range of ages for users to pick.

The age ranges are:

- 1 to 24 months old
- 3 to 17 years old

I have all the logic and model done already and the app runs. The 1 to 24 months displays correctly but the values displayed in the years range is displaying incorrectly. It shows "3 years old" for the majority of the section and "4 years old" for the last three rows. Here is my code:

For some reason for the two else if statements I was given an error that I had to force unwrap the values (if someone could explain that'd be great). The third if statement is where the issue lies with the values.

**Model**

```
struct Age {
var ageMonths: String

static var all: [Age] {
    var ageArray = [Age]()
    for months in 1...24 { // adds months 1 through 24
        ageArray.append(Age(ageMonths: String(months)))
    }
    for months in Array(stride(from: 36, through: 204, by: 12)) { // adds years 3 through 17
        ageArray.append(Age(ageMonths: String(months)))
    }
    return ageArray
    }
}
```

**View Controller**

```
var age: Age?

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

        if Int(Age.all[row].ageMonths) == 1 {
            return Age.all[row].ageMonths + " month old"
        } else if Int(Age.all[row].ageMonths)! > 1 && Int(Age.all[row].ageMonths)! < 36 {
            return Age.all[row].ageMonths + " months old"
        } else if Int(Age.all[row].ageMonths)! >= 36 {
            return Age.all[row/12].ageMonths + " years old"
        }

    return ""
}
```

Comment: 216 months is 18 years old... 204 months is 17 years old

Comment: I know but for the method I used it doesn't include the value for the "to" parameter, so I used the next one.

Comment: Changed it to the other method that uses "through" instead of "to". Thank you for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just have a typo in the last if clause

```
    if Int(Age.all[row].ageMonths)! >= 36 {
        return Age.all[row/12].ageMonths + " years old"
    }
```

but it should be something like this (syntax might be sketchy, I'm just going on memory)

```
    if Int(Age.all[row].ageMonths)! >= 36 {
          let years: Float = Int(Age.all[row].ageMonths)/12
          return "\(years) years old"
    }
```

Comment: That was my first thought to try, but I get the error "Binary operator cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'Int'

Comment: I missed that ageMonths is a string, so you need to do some conversion before you concatenate. I'll edit my reply.

Comment: That worked! Though I made years an Int instead so that I wouldn't get something like "3.0" years in my pickerview. Thanks for the help :)